# rake db:migrate - Mysql2::Error: Table 'database_development.locations' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `locations`

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu-server

Rails 3.2.2

ruby 2.0.0

ubuntu 16.04

myssql server:

Version: 5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1

Version: 5.7.12-0ubuntu1

Version: 5.7.11-0ubuntu6

I run migration, display errors:(see below logs)

When i go in mysql console and select all database, in current list have my db.

I have tried run migrations from another pc, ubuntu 14.04, mysql server: 5.5.49,  everything runs without errors.

How solve this issue? Thank you for advance

**database.yml**

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: projectname_development
  username: root
  password: "123" 
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock


test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: projectname_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 123 
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: projectname_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 123
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock


Warning: Error loading /home/user/projects/projectname/app/models/country.rb:
Mysql2::Error: Table 'projectname_development.locations' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `locations`
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.9.7/lib/patches/db/mysql2.rb:20:in `query'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.9.7/lib/patches/db/mysql2.rb:20:in `query'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `block in execute'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `execute'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:213:in `execute'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:259:in `execute_and_free'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:426:in `columns'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:12:in `block in initialize'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:229:in `yield'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:229:in `columns'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:238:in `columns_hash'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:19:in `descends_from_active_record?'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:25:in `finder_needs_type_condition?'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/base.rb:455:in `relation'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb:37:in `scoped'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/querying.rb:9:in `order'
/home/user/projects/projectname/app/models/country.rb:16:in `<class:Country>'
/home/user/projects/projectname/app/models/country.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `block in load_file'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:639:in `new_constants_in'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:468:in `load_file'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:353:in `require_or_load'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_constant'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.5.2/lib/rspec/core/backward_compatibility.rb:20:in `const_missing'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `each'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `constantize'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:54:in `constantize'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thinking-sphinx-2.0.14/lib/thinking_sphinx/context.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in load_models'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thinking-sphinx-2.0.14/lib/thinking_sphinx/context.rb:54:in `each'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thinking-sphinx-2.0.14/lib/thinking_sphinx/context.rb:54:in `block in load_models'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thinking-sphinx-2.0.14/lib/thinking_sphinx/context.rb:53:in `each'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thinking-sphinx-2.0.14/lib/thinking_sphinx/context.rb:53:in `load_models'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thinking-sphinx-2.0.14/lib/thinking_sphinx/context.rb:15:in `prepare'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thinking-sphinx-2.0.14/lib/thinking_sphinx.rb:82:in `block in context'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thinking-sphinx-2.0.14/lib/thinking_sphinx.rb:79:in `synchronize'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thinking-sphinx-2.0.14/lib/thinking_sphinx.rb:79:in `context'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thinking-sphinx-2.0.14/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record.rb:166:in `define_index'
/home/user/projects/projectname/app/models/group.rb:96:in `<class:Group>'
/home/user/projects/projectname/app/models/group.rb:35:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `block in load_file'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-
```

Comment: locations table present in projectname_development db? , check in mysql console

Comment: No.  SHOW tables;
+----------------------------------+
| Tables_in_projectname_development |
+----------------------------------+
| schema_migrations

Comment: @Dmitrij    Show the migration where you are creating the location table and make sure after running that migration location table is created. if its not then there is a problem with your migration.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have written migration for creating locations table and adding column to locations.

Your migration fails at the time of adding column to locations table as error log says.

step 1 :
Copy create locations table migration file's timestamp  (Not add column timestamp).

step 2 :
Search it in schema_migrations table and delete that record from it.

than `rake db:migrate`

Comment: i think, problem with version mysql and gem mysql2. why than on another pc run I migration and all fine? I clear all from shema.rb. running again rake:db:migrate and same error. schema.rb is empty, i checked now.